# Making non Wordpress pages work on a wordpress site

Tags: php, html

I've got a wordpress website, but I'd like it to also work in a way where I can add other, non-wordpress pages and assess them like a normal website.  In my case, I have a page in the root of my FTP account: http://puu.sh/3IdDY.png  In this case, I want to be able to go to www.labtec901.com/admin.php, which I think I should be able to do, without wordpress coming up and saying it can't find the page: http://puu.sh/3IdI0.png

Comment: Exclude it from being parsed by `index.php` in the .htaccess, by providing a rewriterule that excludes `admin.php`. Although, I must say, this entirely defeats the purpose of wordpress. Moreover, that page exists in the `wp-content` directory, so you'd have to include that path when parsing for `admin.php` in your `.htaccess`.

Comment: I'm not 100% positive this still works, but a couple of years ago I did this using htaccess. Have you tried that? Edit:  Oops, Ohgodwhy beat me to the punch.  :)

Comment: This looks like the wp-contents folder and not the root of your project. I server non wordpress pages in my website which is based on wordpress. The pages are stored in a folder in root directory and it seems to work without tampering `htaccess`